# How to improve performance while processing data from a huge list in C#?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a class `Test1` which call `Test2` class method.

```
public class Test1
{
    public void Testmethod1(List<InputData> request)

    {
        //get data from sql : Huge list inputs around more then 150K
        var inputs = new List<InputData>();
        var output = Test2.Testmethod2(inputs);
    }
}
```

`Test2` class has processing method as below:

```
public class Test2
{
     //request list count 200K
    public static List<OutputData> Testmethod2(List<InputData> request)

    {
        object sync = new Object();
        var output = new List<OutputData>();
        var output1 = new List<OutputData>();
        //data count: 20K
        var data = request.Select(x => x.Input2).Distinct().ToList();
        
        //method calling using for each : processing time 4 hours
        foreach (var n in data)
        {
            output.AddRange(ProcessData(request.Where(x => x.Input1 == n)));

        }

        // method calling using  Parallel.ForEach,processing time 4 hours

        var options = new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 3 };      
        Parallel.ForEach(data, options, n =>
        {
            
            lock (sync)
            {
                output1.AddRange(ProcessData(request.Where(x => x.Input1 == n)));
            }


        });

        return output;
    }



    public static List<OutputData> ProcessData(IEnumerable<InputData> inputData)
    {
        var result = new List<OutputData>();
        //processing on the input data
        return result;

    }

}


public class InputData
{
    public int Input1 { get; set; }
    public int Input2 { get; set; }
    public int Input3 { get; set; }
    public DateTime Input4 { get; set; }
    public int Input5 { get; set; }
    public int Input6 { get; set; }
    public string Input7 { get; set; }
    public int Input8 { get; set; }
    public int Input9 { get; set; }
}

public class OutputData
{
    public int Ouputt1 { get; set; }
    public int Output2 { get; set; }
    public int Output3 { get; set; }
    public int output4 { get; set; }

}
```

its taking quite a long time to process data around 4 hours.Even Parallel.foreach working like normal one.
I am thinking to use Dictionary to store input data however the data is not unique and doesnt have unique row.

Is there a better approach where we can optimize it?

Thanks!

Comment: your only statement within the `Parallel.ForEach` is a locked one, so only a single thread may enter the loop. So of course both approaches are equal here.

Comment: You can always use a dictionary  Dictionary<string,  List<OutputData>> or if key is unique  Dictionary<string,  OutputData>

Comment: You should lock only the shared resources. I suppose **querying** elements doesn´t need to be in the lock, just **writing** the elements to the list, does it?

Comment: As with all questions related to performance, have you profiled to see what code is the slowest first? It's possible all of these are equal because a critical piece of code is holding them all back.

Comment: What does `ProcessData` do? If the query is huge, why not parallelize `request....Distinct()` with PLINQ? All this matters. `Parallel.ForEach` and `PLINQ` are meant for data parallelism, partitioning the source data and passing each partition to a worker task to process independently. This way sychronization overhead is minimized. If you need to use locking, if you need to access shared data, all the parallelization benefits are lost

Comment: Instead of locking inside `Parallel.ForEach` trying to modify a List, you could use a `PLINQ` query and terminate it with `ToList()`, or something more appropriate. A simple `Where` in LINQ-to-Objects scans everything, so it's *very* slow. A dictionary or a better container for the specific problem would accelerate performance immensely

Comment: BTW 20K items is a **tiny** list, unless `ProcessData` does something really expensive. 4 hours for this sounds extreme

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos ProcessData is an expensive function and kind of legacy code. i will check with PLINQ

Comment: @Harsh with so little data, it's probably better to create a dictionary by `Input1` first, and only consider parallelization if that isn't fast enough. Right now you're performing 20K*20K searches. If `Input1` values aren't unique, you can use `ToLookup()` instead of `ToDictionary()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now, the code is using brute force to perform 20K full searches for 20K items. That's 400M iterations.

I suspect performance will improve far more simply by creating a dictionary or a lookup (if there are multiple items per key), eg:

```
var myIndex=request.ToLookup(x=>x.Input1);
var output = new List<OutputData>(20000);
foreach (var n in data)
{
    output.AddRange(ProcessData(myIndex[n]));
}
```

I specify a `capacity` in the list constructor to reduce reallocations each time the list's internal buffer gets full. There's no need for a precise value.

If the code is still slow, one approach would be to use `Parallel.ForEach` or use PLINQ, eg :

```
var output= ( from n in data.AsParallel().WithDegreeOfParallelism(3)
              let dt=myIndex[n]
              select ProcessData(dt)
            ).ToList();
```

Comment: Execution time decreased drastically.i didn't knew that  lookup  can do wonders.i know now.Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
(from n in request
//Group items in request by unique values of Input2
group n by n.Input2)
.AsParallel()
.WithDegreeOfParallelism(4)
.Select(data => Test2.ProcessData(
    //Filter inputs
    data.Where(x => x.Input1 == data.Key)
))
.Cast<IEnumerable<OutputData>>()
//Combine the output
.Aggregate(Enumerable.Concat)
//Generate the final list
.ToList();
```

The idea is to group `request` by `InputData.Input2` values, process the batches in parallel and collect all the results.

Conceptually, this is a variation of @[Panagiotis Kanavos]'s answer